# Apply Jquery .one function on elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following simple Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).one('focus', 'input', function() {
          $(this).val('');
     });
});
</script>

<input type="text" value="Default 1" />
<input type="text" value="Default 2" />
<input type="text" value="Default 3" />
<input type="text" value="Default 4" />
<input type="text" value="Default 5" />
```

The above code will lead to running the focus function only once for all elements.

How to make it run the function once per each input element? Example:

Click the second element, run once. Click the first element, run once. And so on...

Comment: Do you have to delegate the event? normal usage of `one` does the trick.

Comment: If none of the inputs are future added elements then delegation is not necessary.  You could simply use the following `$("input").one('focus', function() {//...});`

Comment: I need to use the function with dynamically generated elements. That's why I'm using this one. Is there another way?

Comment: If your using dynamically generated elements (future added elements), then you could bind to each future added element at the time of generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `not` selector:

```
$(document).on('focus', 'input:not(.focused)', function() {
     $(this).addClass('focused').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works, but I'm guessing what you're really trying to do is use a [`placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/placeholder):

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Default 1" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Default 2" />
```

In [browsers that support placeholder](http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder), you'll get some startup text that clears on focus without taking the performance hit of using javascript.  In unsupported browsers, you can use a polyfill to accomplish what you're trying to do anyway.

Also, the `.each()` function can be used to do something on every element returned by the selector.

#### Here's a simple placeholder polyfill:

```js
$(function(){
    placeholderPolyfill();
});

function placeholderPolyfill() {
    if (!placeholderIsSupported()) {
        $("input[placeholder]").each(function() {
            this.value = this.placeholder;
            $(this).one('focus', function() {
                this.value = '';
            });
        });
    }
}

function placeholderIsSupported() {
    var test = document.createElement('input');
    return ('placeholder' in test);
}
```

### [Here's a demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/An9t6/)